# Replace a word with directory path using sed

Tags: shell, sed

I am writing a shell script, which take parameters as command line arguments and replace the content in a file with the same.

But when I am taking a directory path as command line parameter, I am not able to replace the content in that file with the directory path.

Please find the below content.

```
keep_remote_files =
remote_dir = destination
```

I am trying to replace `destination` with a directory path provided at time of command line execution. (*e.g.*: `/server/path-to-folder/position`).

when using the command

```
sed -i "s/destination/$1/g"
```

while executing;

```
./test "/server/path-to-folder/position"
```

I am getting this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unknown option to `s'
```

can anyone help me on this?

Comment: This solves the issue. Thank you very much for the suggestion.